# Adding custom attribute to date with jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a jquery datepicker which is already getting quite complicated but I want to add in another attribute to the td of certain dates

I already show certain dates as green based on a set of dates in an array (created based on options in a select menu), but I also want to add attributes with other info to these dates.

Here's the code I have so far (including the array for a price which I want to add):

```
$('.propertyAvailabilityCal').datepicker({
beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
    startDates = [];
    startPrice = [];
    selectdatesElem = $(input).siblings("select.startdates");
    $(input).siblings("select.startdates").find("option").each( function() {
          var startdateParts = $(this).val().split(', ');
              startDates.push(startdateParts[0] + ", " + (parseInt(startdateParts[1], 10)-1) + ", " + parseInt(startdateParts[2], 10));
    });
    $(input).siblings("select.startprice").find("option").each( function() {
          startPrice.push($(this).val());
    });


},
beforeShowDay: function(date) {

    for (i = 0; i < startDates.length; i++) {
          if (date.getFullYear()+", "+date.getMonth()+", "+date.getDate() == startDates[i]) {
                return [true, 'eventDay', date];
          }
    }

    return [false, ''];
}
});
```

And:

```
<select class="startPrice">
    <option value="274.95"></option>
    <option value="274.95"></option>
    <option value="274.95"></option>
    <option value="274.95"></option>
    <option value="274.95"></option>
</select>
<select class="startdates">
    <option value="2013, 06, 28"></option>
    <option value="2013, 07, 01"></option>
    <option value="2013, 07, 08"></option>
    <option value="2013, 07, 11"></option>
    <option value="2013, 07, 18"></option>
</select>
```

I want to be able to add the price as an attribute to that date. Is this even possible and if so does anyone know how?

Here's a jsfiddle to show what I want to achieve but with the price appearing rather than the date when you hover over a date...

http://jsfiddle.net/9tapA/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BNLdz/)

btw, `$(input).siblings("select.startPrice")`. remember css selectors are case sensitive